# Redirect subdomain to user profile

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I'm trying to redirect a subdomain user to his profile.
For example: If user requested user.example.com
he gets redirected to example.com/user

I searched a lot, and most answers were old and didn't work.

Things I have done:

1. Created A record with *.example.com.
2. Enabled wildcard redirect to example.com (I actually don't know if
   this is needed) some Stack Overflow answer provided that.
3. Created subdomain in my hosting like *.example.com (but this caused
   all my subdomains get redirected to the main landing page, which is
   example.com) some Stack Overflow answers provided that.
4. In my larave project routes.

```
Route::domain('{name}'.'example.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{name}', 'usersController@profile');
});
```

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.example.com'], function () {
        Route::get('/{name}', 'usersController@profile');
    });
```

I'm really lost between old Stack Overflow answers and PHP hard code. All I want is simple. If user requested user.example.com he gets redirected to his profile example.com/user then he can navigate normally like no need for subdomain later.

I don't know what I'm missing or doing wrong!

Comment: This also can be done from server end config. eg if apache, .htaccess will be helpful.

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: can try this out.

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

Comment: This worked for me ---->RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/%1/$1 [L,R=301,QSA] 
Your answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to know this this worked out for you. Here i am dropping a formatted answer of it. Can help others.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) example.com/%1/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).